# When I search for apps, what determines the order in which they are ranked?

Tags: google-play-store

When I search for apps in the Google Play Store, what is the determining factor of the order in which they are presented to me?

Is it the number of downloads? Or reviews? Or total star rating?

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably a complex algorithm that google uses. It is probably based on a number of factors, including all the things you listed, and things like your device type. knowing google, it could even base it on the types of apps that you use/install.

Comment: @RyanConrad has the right idea (It's hidden from us), but I've noticed that "Top Developers'" apps are consistently above all others.

Answer (score 0):

Its a combination of the three, plus more. Google play store factors in what you like (e.g. the "like installed apps" tab) the popularity (which is also the only factor of the "top [insert catetrgory that's not grossing here), how much money the app is making and its overall rating. Apps marked as editors choice have their own tab, but **don't** get shoved up to the top of the other categories unless they should be there for whatever reason applies.